# Is there a standard order for logging levels, from quiet to verbose?

Tags: language-agnostic, logging

Many logging systems allow you to filter the logs by 'log level', where the levels are integers with names like 'DEBUG', 'INFO', and 'ERROR'.  My question is, is DEBUG always **less than** ERROR?  Or does this depend on the system?  I know there's no guarantee that a system follows the standard, but I'm just curious whether there is a mode of thinking that most logging systems adhere to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s true in Python’s logging module and in Android. And it makes sense if you describe the field as “priority”, since an ERROR will always have a higher priority than a DEBUG. I would be surprised to find a logger with the levels inverted.

Answer (score 7):

There is no industry standard for logging levels.  A commonly followed convention is debug < info < warn < error < fatal.